# Push method in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Hi I have a problem in javascript.

when i try to save info in the localStorage  in  console i had  the error  'method 'push' of undefined.

```
<script type="text/javascript">                  

//localStorage.clear(); // Clears the hard drive (database)
var oUsers = {aIds:[], aNames:[]}; 

// Default            
if(localStorage.sUsers){
    console.log('Users already in memory');
    // Get the string with users from the database and
    // convert it into an object, so we can use it
    oUsers = JSON.parse(localStorage.sUsers); 
} 

function SaveUser(){
    // Take the text and make it an object                          
    oUsers.aIds.push(document.getElementById("TxtId").value);
    oUsers.aNames.push(document.getElementById("TxtName").value);               
    localStorage.sUsers = JSON.stringify(oUsers);
    console.log(localStorage.sUsers);                
}              

</script>
```

Comment: Did you get any error message?

Comment: It sounds like your `oUsers` no longer has the property you are trying to push into. Check if `JSON.parse(localStorage.sUsers)` returns the structure you expect.

Comment: Are you sure that `localStorage.clear();` isn't resetting your types from array to something that doesn't implement a push method?

Comment: We need more info on this code. As it appears it should be fine. Without more code samples I'd guess two things: you're losing the array's during the serialization process because they're empty (could be a localStorage quirk?) or there's a bug in your code and later on down the line you're trying to call ``push`` on a JSON string.

Comment: To help us out how about putting a ``console.log(typeof oUsers.aIds);`` on the first line of ``SaveUser()``. That seems like a great place to start.